# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors when using lottie

Tags: android

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

Here is my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

// RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0"

}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.learnapplication">
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.customtabs"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CustomTabActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show manifest?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the manifest code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try removing `-alpha3` from custom tabs dependency then try to rebuild.

Comment: No it is not working
Instead proving me suggestion

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-23:19 to override.

But this is also not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no problem with the Gradle or with the manifest, I'm also looking for the solution to this problem and in the manifest you do not have to change anything, rather use as minimum version of the SDK at least 21 and to avoid confiscations, try to go down version of Lottie (I'm using 2.7.0) and try adding in the Gradle this few lines:

```
implementation ('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'transition'
}
```

Good luck bro! Update me!

Comment: @AkankshaPaul I'm happy! Thumb up! :D

Comment: Downgrading Lottie version to 2.7.0 and adding these lines helped me. Thanks a lot.